# Can the multiplication of chars/digits be made more performant?

Tags: c, performance, gcc

I have following code where a sum is calculated, based on a very large series.

The series `char *a` is a char array, which contains digits only (0..9).

I wanted to ask if there is any possibility to make the code faster. It is currently a bottle neck in a distributed computing application.

A small reproduction code. Not the actual code, and more simplified.

```
int top = 999999999;

char *a;
a = (char*) calloc(top+1, sizeof(char));

// ... fill a with initial values ...

for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;

    for (m = 1, k = top; m < k; ++m, --k) {
        // Here is the bottle neck!!
        sum += a[m]*a[k];
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);

    // ... Add something at the end of a, and increase top ...
}
```

**I have already tried following:**

1. Optimizing the code with `-O3` (gcc compiler). The compiler line is now:

   ```
   gcc -c -Wall -fopenmp -Wno-unused-function -O3 -std=c99 -g0 -march=native -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -fwhole-program -fprefetch-loop-arrays -funsafe-loop-optimizations -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -fselective-scheduling -fselective-scheduling2 -fsel-sched-pipelining -fsel-sched-pipelining-outer-loops -fgcse-sm -fgcse-lm -fgcse-las -fmodulo-sched -fgcse-after-reload -fsee -DLIBDIVIDE_USE_SSE2 -DLIBDIVIDE_USE_SSE4_1 xxx.c -o xxx.o
   ```
2. Using of [GNU openMP](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) to split the for-loop to multiple cores

   ```
   unsigned long long int halfway = (top>>1) + 1; // = top/2 + 1
   // digits is defined as top+1

   #pragma omp parallel // firstprivate/*shared*/(a, digits, halfway)
   for (unsigned long long int m = 1; m < halfway; ++m) {
       sum += a[m] * a[digits-m];
   }
   ```

   Result: Much, much faster, but requires more cores, and I still would like to make it faster.
3. Casting `a[m]` to `unsigned long long int` before multiplication

   ```
   sum += (unsigned long long int)a[m] * a[k];
   ```

   Result: A small performance boost.
4. Using a multiplication lookup table, because an array-lookup is faster than the actual multiplication.

   ```
   sum += multiply_lookup[a[m]][a[k]]; // a[m]*a[k];
   ```

   Result: A small performance boost.
5. I have tried to find a mathematical solution to reduce operations, but it seems like nothing can be optimized, mathematically seen.

**I have following idea for optimization:**

I [have read](http://computer-programming-forum.com/46-asm/5d298759ca2e2d44.htm) that the multiplication of floats (asm `fmul`) is much faster than the multiplication of integers (asm `mul`). Just changing `int` to `float` doesn't help -- but I think the code might become much more performant if the work is done using MMX or SSE instruction sets, or if the work is done by the FPU. Although I have some assembler knowledge, I have no knowledge about these topics.

However, if you have additional ideas how to optimize it, I am glad to hear them.

**Update** Some additional information:

- The series grows by 1 element after each loop.
- While the series grows, `top` gets increased.
- When `top` is reaching the array limit, `a` will get increased by 100000 bytes using `realloc()`.
- Platform: Debian Linux Jessie x64, on an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3440  @ 2.53GHz

**Additional off-topic question:** Do you know the mathematical name of this sum, where the pairs of elements of the series are multiplied from outside to inside?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no code review site.

Comment: It is not a code review. I want to know how a fast 8-bit multiplication in assembler is possible.

Comment: You have running code and ask for optimisation. This requires very well a code-review. And the multiplications will not be performed in 8 bits anyway. This is C.

Comment: @Olaf: Optimization questions are generally on topic for SO. There isn't enough code here for a proper post to CodeReview.SE. This is a perfectly acceptable question on SO.

Comment: There is alot you can do to speed it up.  Don't use [] to access array elements, use pointer increments instead.  Let me know if you know how to do that... I don't see why this should be closed, he has a bottleneck - very common and useful solutions

Comment: @Cornstalks: I disagree. And I did not say this should be moved to code review as-is; of course OP has to provide more for CR. Maybe he can make it acceptable here, but as-is it is not.

Comment: Can you make any alignment guarantees about `a`? What platform is this going to run on? Can the computation overflow? I need more details.

Comment: @Olaf: Look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). This question definitely fits in the "on-topic" box on that page (and definitely doesn't fit in the "off-topic" box).

Comment: Also, is it possible to re-arrange the items in `a`? If they followed a simpler pattern, the compiler might be able to vectorize this code yielding a potential 8-fold performance increase.

Comment: Exactly pedants!  Lets answer the general query - Yes lots can be done to fix the 'problem' he has, especially using C - we have enough information in his question to start with...

Comment: @FUZxxl The series grows by 1 element after each loop.

While the series grows, `top` gets increased.
When `top` is reaching the array limit, `a` will get increased by 100000 bytes using `realloc()`.
Platform: Linux x64. I made sure nothing can overflow. The series cannot be re-arranged. Its contents are digits without specific pattern, like the digits of the number Pi.

Comment: @DanielMarschall Could you provide any more details? What are the values that go in the array? Perhaps there's improvement potential there.

Comment: Did you consider [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34255073/841108) to a similar question....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What do you exactly mean? I use GMP at a different point of the program, but not for the calculation of the sum. The sum won't overflow with 64 bit. Having the sum being GMP would make things just more slow.

Comment: Come on guys, you might dislike this question, but it's certainly not broad, if anything it's too narrow.

Comment: @harold Yes, I wondered that too. 2 hours ago, there were only 3 votes. I wonder where the remaining 2 came so quickly.

Comment: I have re-phrased my initial post. I mentioned the idea of FPU/SSE from beginning on, because that was my guess for optimization. Also, I have provided much more information of what I had tried, just to have more code in it -- maybe other people will find it useful.

Comment: By the way, the kind of operation you want to do is called a *discrete convolution* and there is an [efficient algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms) for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the little-known PMADDUBSW (Multiply and Add Packed Signed and Unsigned Bytes) for this. The signed/unsigned business doesn't matter here, everything is in the interval [0 .. 9] anyway. The add is saturating, but that doesn't matter here because 9*9 is only 81. With intrinsics that's `_mm_maddubs_epi16`. Because the `k` index goes down, you have to byte-reverse it, which you can do with PSHUFB (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`). An annoying thing happens when the indexes "meet" in the middle, you can do that part one by one..

Here's a try, only *slightly* tested:

```
__m128i sum = _mm_setzero_si128();
int m, k;
for (m = 1, k = top - 15; m + 15 < k; m += 16, k -= 16) {
   __m128i am = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(a + m));
   __m128i ak = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(a + k));
   ak = _mm_shuffle_epi8(ak, _mm_set_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15));
   sum = _mm_add_epi16(sum, _mm_maddubs_epi16(am, ak));
}
// could use phaddw, but I do this the long way to avoid overflow slightly longer
sum = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_unpacklo_epi16(sum, _mm_setzero_si128()),
                    _mm_unpackhi_epi16(sum, _mm_setzero_si128()));
sum = _mm_hadd_epi32(sum, sum);
sum = _mm_hadd_epi32(sum, sum);
int s = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum);
// this is for the "tail"
k += 15;
for (; m < k; ++m, --k)
    s += a[m] * a[k];
```

Also I ignore overflow. You can do this for (2<sup>16</sup>-1)/(2*81) = 404 iterations and still definitely have no overflow. If you need more, periodically add this to a 32bit result.

In a quick benchmark, this is about 7 times as fast as the simple way (tested with 2KB of random data on a 4770K, taking the best out of a hundred runs for each).

Using pointers as suggested by an other answer improves it further, to about 9 times as fast as the simple way. With indices there was some weird sign-extension going on.

```
int foobar(char* a, int top)
{
    __m128i sum = _mm_setzero_si128();

    char *m, *k;
    for (m = a + 1, k = a + top - 15; m + 15 < k; m += 16, k -= 16) {
       __m128i am = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(m));
       __m128i ak = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(k));
       ak = _mm_shuffle_epi8(ak, _mm_set_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15));
       sum = _mm_add_epi16(sum, _mm_maddubs_epi16(am, ak));
    }

    sum = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_unpacklo_epi16(sum, _mm_setzero_si128()),
                        _mm_unpackhi_epi16(sum, _mm_setzero_si128()));
    sum = _mm_hadd_epi32(sum, sum);
    sum = _mm_hadd_epi32(sum, sum);
    int s = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum);

    k += 15;
    for (; m < k; ++m, --k)
        s += *m * *k;

    return s;
}
```

---

Split up in parts, still about 9 times as fast as the original despite the extra logic:

```
int foobar(char* a, int top)
{
    int s = 0;
    char *m, *k;
    for (m = a + 1, k = a + top - 15; m + 15 < k;) {
        __m128i sum = _mm_setzero_si128();
        for (int i = 0; i < 404 && m + 15 < k; m += 16, k -= 16, ++i) {
           __m128i am = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(m));
           __m128i ak = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(k));
           ak = _mm_shuffle_epi8(ak, _mm_set_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15));
           sum = _mm_add_epi16(sum, _mm_maddubs_epi16(am, ak));
        }
        sum = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_unpacklo_epi16(sum, _mm_setzero_si128()),
                            _mm_unpackhi_epi16(sum, _mm_setzero_si128()));
        sum = _mm_hadd_epi32(sum, sum);
        sum = _mm_hadd_epi32(sum, sum);
        s += _mm_cvtsi128_si32(sum);
    }

    k += 15;
    for (; m < k; ++m, --k)
        s += *m * *k;

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Wow, you seem to have a lot of knowledge with that!
But it doesn't work at the moment. I think something relating to SSE is not included or not available in gcc?
`error: unknown type name '__m128i'` .

Comment: The compiler line is `gcc -c -Wall -fopenmp -Wno-unused-function -O3 -std=c99 -g0 -march=native -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -m64 -fwhole-program -fprefetch-loop-arrays -funsafe-loop-optimizations -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -fselective-scheduling -fselective-scheduling2 -fsel-sched-pipelining -fsel-sched-pipelining-outer-loops -fgcse-sm -fgcse-lm -fgcse-las -fmodulo-sched -fgcse-after-reload -fsee -DLIBDIVIDE_USE_SSE2 -DLIBDIVIDE_USE_SSE4_1 -DWITH_SSE2=ON -S -masm=intel -fverbose-asm  xx.c -o xx.asm` .

Comment: You need something like `#include <x86intrin.h>` for this

Comment: @DanielMarschall More than half of the flags you pass are implied by `-O3`.

Comment: @harold Thanks. It compiles, but I think something is still wrong. Here are some compiler warnings and my code http://pastebin.com/d5w2A4Fh .

Comment: @FUZxxl Yes. I should correct that in future. I have (and am) very much experimenting with performance that it is a back and forth. I try a lot of different things, benchmark, change, benchmark, change. So it's all a bit messy, until I have found a solution with optimal performance.

Comment: @DanielMarschall you can ignore the crying about the pointer type or just add a cast. printf-ing an __m128i is not as easy as you attempt there though, and anyway it contains (this time) words not dwords.  You could store it to an array of uint16_t's and print those.

Comment: @harold I think I understand how __m128i works now. I am not 100% sure, but I think I found a possibility how to use the last 32 bits. But I just figured out that there seems to be a problem. Since you are using 16-byte chunks, the sum calculation is not correct. For example, if top=5 , the sum will be 0. (`a` grows during each iteration by 1 digit, so does `top`)  http://pastebin.com/EdiXYeLN

Comment: @DanielMarschall because the data is too short, everything is the tail. So it does literally nothing. Just do the tail one by one.

Comment: @harold With "tail" you mean the area between `top-15` and `top` ?
But this "tail" needs to be multiplied with the "head", which would be the area between `1` and `16`. But `1..16` is already covered in the loop.
I am a bit stuck and confused at the moment.

Comment: @harold And if I use a top=19, I get a `__m128i` value of `{97, 157, 201, 229, 241, 237, 217, 181}` . What does that mean? I thought the last 32 bit are the actual 32 bit values of the sum

Comment: @DanielMarschall the part that wasn't done yet. I've edited in the handling for the tail now. The part from top-15 to top actually *is* done.

Comment: @harold Thank you so much for your effort and time you are spending. I highly appreciate it. I have now implemented it in the real code and tested it. It seems to work, but I fear I ran into an overflow ... at `top=49594`, the reference sum and the new sum are different (Actual: 439021, Expected: 504557). `top` should reach 667,000,000 -- in my old code, `sum` as 64 bit value (`unsigned long long int`) did not overflow. -- I am still trying to understand your code. I find it highly interested, but I have problems finding good SSE documentation for these functions.

Comment: @DanielMarschall it can happen from top=12928 and up. You can do it in parts then, although from the way you write maybe you can't figure out how that would work, so perhaps I'll add it

Comment: @harold 
Wow, thank you so much; you are awesome! For me, it actually speed up 10 times!
There would be just 1 last wish (and I am sorry that I am so untaught in this topic; I want to learn it)
From previous calculations, I know that `sum` will have a 32-bit overflow somewhere around top=190,000,000 , so I was using `unsigned long long int` (however, a signed one would work too).
I tried to upgrade your code to 64 bit.

Comment: @harold Simply changing the last line to `_mm_cvtsi128_si64` doesn't help, and changing every 16->32 and every 32->64 didn't help, as some functions do not exist.
When I changed the last line to `_mm_cvtsi128_si64`, I receive
the result 0x12300000123, although it should only be 0x123 . Are the additional 32bit on the left not initialized?
http://pastebin.com/XSfZ5Zk2

Comment: @DanielMarschall you can extend this to 64bit sums just by changing the type of `s` and the return type, the cvt-whatever stays the same (it's still the sum over the same length of stuff, it's not overflowing yet there)

Comment: @harold Thank you very much for all your help! I just tested it with  top=690,000,000 and compared with the previous calculations -- it works perfectly! Tomorrow I will try if it can be made multi-core-compatible using openMP. This would break the sonic barrier ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This loop,

```
for (m = 1, k = top; m < k; ++m, --k) {
    // Here is the bottle neck!!
    sum += a[m]*a[k];
}
```

could gain benefit from changing to:

```
char *b = a + top;
a++;
for (; a < b; ) 
{
    sum += ( *a++ ) * ( *b--);
}
```

By removing the [] you are saving alot of arithmetic for every access into the array.  This halves the theoretical number of address computations from:
4 with  `++m --k` and `a[m]  a[k]` to 
2 with `*a++  *b--`

Simple pointer increment is cheaper and usually faster overall, as array access is not always optimized perfectly using the [].

Hope this helps

Comment: Address computations are generally free on modern architectures. x86 processors actually have dedicated ALUs just for address computation. If anything, this is going to confuse the compiler even more.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I thought that too, but I just tested his code and this answer gave a ~5.2x speedup.

Comment: You may be right, but I doubt it is perfectly 'free'.  Perhaps the SO can try it and see.

Comment: @Cornstalks Can you show me the code you benchmarked with? This is interesting.

Comment: @FUZxxl: [this is the code I profiled with](http://pastebin.com/aeHX3KbR). Dead simple (too simple, really). I think the subscript access really threw off the optimizer. With subscript accessing, things take longer if I change `i<10` to `i<20`. However, without subscript accessing (i.e. this answer), it's always constant time. I suspect the optimizer has an easier time optimizing the outer `for`-loop (and just changing it to a constant multiply) away when incremental pointers are used.

Comment: @Cornstalks I suspect the compiler knows that `a` is constant zero and optimizes away everything.

Comment: For curiosity - I would find it interesting to see a Watcom compiler in action with this...Apparently it was one of the fastest.  But my info is old

Comment: @FUZxxl: If that's the case, then `0.9` seconds is a really long time to run a program that's been entirely optimized away. I don't think the optimizer has optimized *everything* away. If I change the outer `for`-loop to be `i<1`, they have approximately the same running time. That suggests to me that the optimizer isn't optimizing everything away. I just looked at the disassembly and it doesn't optimize everything away. I don't have time to analyze it in depth but it's certainly got the for-multiply-add loop in there.

Comment: @FUZxxl about the indexing/pointer thing, I thought so too but apparently indexing with 32bit ints in 64bit code is annoying, with sign extensions.

Comment: @harold Which is why you should always index with `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

The operation you want to perform is called a [*discrete convolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution), it appears when multiplying large numbers. The naïve algorithm you use has a complexity of O(*n* <sup>2</sup>), but an O(*n* log *n*) solution obtains using a [*discrete Fourier transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).

## Discrete Convolutions

The discrete convolution *c* = *a* ∗ *b* of two sequences *a* = *a*<sub>0</sub>, *a*<sub>1</sub>, …, *a*<sub>*n* − 1</sub> and *b* = *b*<sub>0</sub>, *b*<sub>1</sub>, …, *b*<sub>*n* − 1</sub> with *n* elements each is a sequence of 2*n* − 1 elements defined for each *k* as the sum:

> *c*<sub>*i*</sub> = ∑<sub>max(0, *i* − *n* + 1) ≤ *j* < min(*n*, *i* + 1)</sub> *a*<sub>*j*</sub> *b*<sub>*i* − *j*</sub>

If we assume that *a*<sub>*i*</sub> = *b*<sub>*i*</sub> = 0 for *i* ∉ {0, …, *n* − 1}, then we can simplify this and sum over all integer *i*:

> *c*<sub>*i*</sub> = ∑<sub>*j*</sub> *a*<sub>*j*</sub> *b*<sub>*i* − *j*</sub>

Notice how this is the operation you want to perform: *a* = *b*  = `a[]` and the `i`-th iteration of your loop, `sum` is just out *c*<sub>*i*</sub>.

The discrete convolution is well-studied and appears in a number of mathematical problems related to signal-processing, combinatorics and statistics. Fortunately, it can be computed in superlinear time O(*n* log *n*) instead of the naïve O(*n*<sup>2</sup>).

## Cyclic Discrete Convolutions

We can expand *b* to *b*<sub>*N*</sub> such that

> *b*<sub>*k*</sub> = *b*<sub>*k* mod *n*, or
>
>   *b*<sub>*N*</sub> = *b*<sub>0</sub>, *b*<sub>1</sub>, …, *b*<sub>*n* − 1</sub>, *b*<sub>0</sub>, …, *b*<sub>*n* − 1</sub>, *b*<sub>0</sub>, …</sub>

This is called the *cyclic expansion* of *b* to *b*<sub>*N*</sub>. The discrete convolution *a* ∗ *b*<sub>*N*</sub> is called the *discrete cyclic convolution* of *a* and *b*.

Note that the non-cyclic discrete convolution of *a* and *b* can be computed from a cyclic convolution by appending sufficiently many zeroes to *a* and *b* before convolving such that the cyclic expansion of *b* doesn't alter the result. See [this article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnelle_Faltung#.C3.9Cberlappungsfehler) for more details.

## Discrete Fourier Transform

The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) transforms a sequence of samples *a* into a complex frequency spectrum ℱ(*a*) of the sampled signal. The Fourier transform is invertible and computable in superlinear time O(*n* log *n*) using various [*fast Fourier transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) (FFT) algorithms. This transform has many applications in signal-processing. It has the useful property that

> *a* ∗ *b**N* = ℱ<sup>−1</sup>(ℱ(*a*) × ℱ(*b*))

That is, the cyclic convolution of two sequences *a* and *b* is element-wise multiplication under Fourier transform. Since element-wise multiplication can be done in linear time, this makes it possible to compute the result you need in total time O(*n* log *n*).

## Implementation

The [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) project provides highly optimized implementations of the fast Fourier transform.

## Problems

Fourier transforms work on complex numbers and requires a floating-point unit to be fast. The result is likely slightly imprecise. As far as I know, precise methods are possible with some modulo magic (this is what's used in the Schönhage-Strassen algorithm for large-integer multiplication) but I'm not sure about the details.

Comment: So it looks like i am searching 
**Sum = (a*a) [top]**? But the definition shows that m goes from -inf to +inf ; so the case that the sum stops once both sides meet each other,  isn't there? I do not quite understand why you are referring that algorithm in re multiplying large numbers ; isn't the actual problem doing a lot of multiplications of digits into a huge sum? How are they related to a bigint multiplication?

Comment: @DanielMarschall The sum goes from −∞ to ∞ but your series is 0 on all but the entries 0 to *n* − 1, so all but at most *n* terms of the convolution are zero. Ever done long multiplication (schriftliches multiplizieren)? You basically do the kind of operation and then sum up all the sums shifted by a power of 10 to get a result. [This page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnelle_Faltung) might be more useful to you.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this is the solution http://pastebin.com/C1WLbRXj . I did long multiplication long ago, but I don't understand how this solves the problem. Don't the carry values destroy the calculation? If I did multiply 123*654 using Base 81, then the resulting number {6, 10, 12} could be used to form the sum = 6+10+12 = 28.

Comment: Update: A better solution than the one I wrote in pastebin:
**a={1,2,3}; b={4,5,6}; (a*b)[2] = 28**
It seems that this is a 1D convolution. (Actually, I worked with (2D) convolution before when I implemented a quick'n'dirty Photoshop filter. But it was slow, and used only simple multiplication).

Comment: @DanielMarschall See the article I linked, multiplication can be implemented with convolution and Schönhage-Strassen does so. You can compute cyclic convolutions with a fast-FFT and element-wise multiplications (so *n* instead of *n*² multiplications), by padding the input to 2*n* entries, the cyclic convolution becomes equal to a linear convolution, see the article *Schnelle Faltung* I linked.

Comment: Believe me, I have read most of it in the time between. But my math knowledge is not that far. I haven't studied math -- I am just a "normal" programmer.

Comment: @DanielMarschall I see. Do you know what an FFT (Fast Fourier Transformation) is? I can try to explain the underlying concepts in my answer but I need to know what kind of knowledge I can assume for that.

Comment: Actually, no, and it is a bit embarassing for me. Maybe it is better to ask the way the things I DO understand ;-)
* I do understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution and how it is related to solve my problem.
* I do understand the idea behind convolution, and I used 2D convolution on image processing before.
* I do understand that the 1D convolution is what I need. With the input being {1,2,3} and the kernel {4,5,6}
* I do know the long multiplication.
* I do how that each number is a polynomial sum, e.g. 123 = 1^100 + 2^10 + 3, and can be splitted this way.

Comment: This code http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-schonhage-strassen-algorithm-multiplication-two-numbers/ seems to implement the Schönehage-Strassen-Algorithm and calculate a linear convolution, but I see a lot of modulos and divisions, so I have no idea how this algorithm can be considered as fast, or the implementation is just too simple.

Comment: @DanielMarschall That implementation is incorrect—it doesn't do the important thing which is using an FFT to cut down the time for the convolution. Please don't use it. I'm going to post some more details tomorrow once I got some sleep.

Comment: @DanielMarschall Please read the expanded answer. Is it useful to you?

Comment: The precise variant you allude to is the number-theoretic transform, it's really just an FFT over a finite field

Comment: Thank you. I hoped there is an easy-to-understand way to explain **why** FFT works, but I fear this is not as easy, and probably can only be explained with a mathematical proof.
**(1)** In your post you write "a = b = a[]", but that doesn't seem to be correct. a has to be the lower half of a[], and b the upper half of a[], otherwise the sum would overlap.
**(2)** It seems like I need `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d`, but I have lost a bit the overview. What is exactly the plan to get `sum`? Is it correct that I run the FFT over a[], and then sum the output array together (but they are complex numbers)?

Comment: **(3)** You mention that the complex output might not be precise. Is it possible that the rounding-errors will sum up, so that the real number `sum` is wrong (i.e. +1/-1)?
**(4)** Are you familar with the FFTW framework? What do I need for NTT ? There seems to be a project called NTTW, but it seems to be outdated.

Comment: @DanielMarschall (1) This applies if we would do a linear convolution. Since the FFT only allows us to do a cyclic convolution, we have to pad a with as many zeros, but we don't have to pad a and b differently. (2) I've never used the libfftw, but [this page](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html#Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs) should serve as a good introduction to the work flow. (3) Yes. (4) No. I've literally never uses Fourier transforms, I just recall that they solve your problem.